# We have set URL response threshold 18 Sec in monitoring tool, and getting most of the alerts are 35 to 40 sec in between

Tags: central-administration

We have set URL response threshold 18 Sec in monitoring tool, and getting most of the alerts are 35 to 40 sec in between.I could see in browser, When actually opens on server its not taking that much time.What is the best way to reduce these alerts.More over this is central administration web app.

Idea 1: I can't ask tools team to increase the threshold.because share point  loads page 20 sec ideally and also not good practice to increase threshold too high.

Comment: Are u monitoring central admin or other content web application? Which tool u are using?

Comment: Centarl Admin, which is only mocking noise.Nimsoft

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't monitor the central admin site. Central admin is low traffic site or littlly only for SharePoint admin using it(only 1 or 2 users).

With low traffic site, it is common that when no activity then app pool drop the cache. Next time someone hit the central admin then IIS will again build the cache for web application.

Comment: that's right.I have one more idea. If i stop SharePoint admin service then what happens?

Comment: Admin service will hurt the admin related services like deployment of solution etc. Not a good idea

Comment: thank you! in that case how to monitor central admin URL?

Comment: is there any service related to central admin in SP?

Comment: Which SharePoint version u are using?in SharePoint 2016 there is a service which u can turn on/off

Comment: I am using Sp 2010?